# Reactjs: Rewriting Jquery app to Reactjs for deleting contents

Tags: reactjs

Reactjs: Rewriting Jquery app to Reactjs for deleting contents.

I used the **jquery** code below to delete records by selecting on multiple checkbox and its working fine.

Now I want to 
implement the same function(Delete multiple records) using **reactjs**.

The Problem with Reactjs Code is that its not deleting any records. there is no error in the console. when I check the 
backend, no user id is posted as check parameter is empty. This is what am seeing at the backend

```
{"check":""}stdClass Object
(
    [check] => 
)
```

but I believe am supposed to be seeing eg

`[check] => 123 etc` based on delete userid being sent

Here is the working Jquery php code

```
<?php 
include "config.php";
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src='jquery-3.0.0.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>


$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#delete').click(function(){

        var post_arr = [];
        $('#recordsTable input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
            if (jQuery(this).is(":checked")) {
                var id = this.id;
                var splitid = id.split('_');
                var postid = splitid[1];

                post_arr.push(postid);

            }
        });

        if(post_arr.length > 0){

            // AJAX Request
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajaxfile.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { post_id: post_arr},
                success: function(response){
                    $.each(post_arr, function( i,l ){
                        $("#tr_"+l).remove();
                    });
                }
            });

        }      
    });

});

</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='container'>
            <!-- Delete button -->
            <input type='button' value='Delete' id='delete'><br><br>

            <!-- Table -->
            <table border='1' id='recordsTable' >
                <tr style='background: whitesmoke;'>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                </tr>

                <?php 
                $query = "SELECT * FROM users";
                $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

                $count = 1;
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ){
                    $id = $row['id'];
                    $age = $row['age'];
                    $name = $row['name'];

                ?>
                    <tr id='tr_<?= $id ?>'>
                        <td><input type='checkbox' id='del_<?php echo $id; ?>' ></td>
                        <td><a href='<?= $link; ?>'><?= $title; ?></a></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php
                    $count++;
                }
                ?>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Here is what I have tried with Reactjs**

```
    import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
    import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
    import axios from 'axios';
class CheckBoxm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    //this.toggleChangeJB = this.toggleChangeJB.bind(this);
 //this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);


this.useridChanged = this.useridChanged.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      rec: [
        { id: 1, name: "Tony", Age: "18" , gender: "male" },
        { id: 2, name: "John", Age: "21" , gender: "female"},
        { id: 3, name: "Luke", Age: "78" , gender: "male"},
        { id: 4, name: "Mark", Age: "90" , gender: "female"},
        { id: 5, name: "Jame", Age: "87" , gender: "female"},
        { id: 6, name: "Franco", Age: "34" , gender: "male"},
        { id: 7, name: "Franco", Age: "34" , gender: "male"},
        { id: 8, name: "Biggard", Age: "19" , gender: "male"},
        { id: 9, name: "tom", Age: "89" , gender: "female"}
      ],

chrk: false,
//chrk: '',

    };

  }


toggleChangeJB = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      chrk: !prevState.chrk,
    }));
  }

  useridChanged(e) {
        this.setState({
            chrk: e.target.value
        });
    }


  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
 //const { chrk} = this.state;

    let arr = [];
    for (var key in this.state.chrk) {
      if(this.state.chrk[key] === true) {
        arr.push(key);
      }
    }
    let data = {
      check: arr.toString() 
    };

    axios.post('http://localhost/apidb_react/checkbox.php', data)
          .then(res => console.log(res.data));
  }



  render() {
    return (
      <div >
        <div>
          <h3>Delete Multiple Records with Checkbox</h3>


<form onSubmit = {this.onSubmit}>


          <ul>
            {this.state.rec.map((obj, i) => (
              <li key={i}>

                 <input type="checkbox" name="chrk" value={obj.id}

                onChange={this.useridChanged}
              />{obj.name} - {obj.Age}  - {obj.gender}- ({obj.id})


              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>


 <button className="btn btn-primary">
              Submit
            </button>

        </form>

        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `check: arr.toString()`, using the `toString` method is not the same as serializing to json! Axios should take care of the serialization anyways, so just use `const data = { check: arr };`. There may be a few more problems in the code, but it's a start :-)

Comment: Sir Alexander Derck, If I implement your suggestion. it shows empty at the backend. here is the response {"check":[]}stdClass Object
(
    [check] => Array
        (
        )

)  it seems no userid is posted.

Comment: So now the serialization is correct, but apparantly the array you are sending is empty. Best way is to use the debugger (I recommend google chrome debugger) and set a breakpoint to step through the code and see why nothing gets added to your array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution that partly works for me by updating only the **onSubmit()** function code. The solution still has one downtime as it only send the last selected value to the server side. At this junction, this the best solution I have for now with help from Mr. Alexander Deck..

```
onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
 const { chrk} = this.state;
//let arr = [];
const arr = [];
arr.push(chrk);

const data = { check: arr };
alert(arr);
    axios.post('http://localhost/apidb_react/checkbox.php', data)
          .then(res => console.log(res.data));
  }
```